# vue 2 filter multiple array

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

Excuse me, my json data have two array.

I want to filter this json data(banner_img:['img']) with Vue.js.

But Analysis Json data is some problems..

Json data

```
[{"id":10,"banner":"AIR","banner_img":[{"id":1,"img":"air_1.png","banner_id":10},{"id":2,"img":"air_2.png","banner_id":10}]},
{"id":11,"banner":"HOT","banner_img":[{"id":3,"img":"hot_1.png","banner_id":11},{"id":4,"img":"hot_2.png","banner_id":11}]},
{"id":12,"banner":"NEW","banner_img":[{"id":5,"img":"new_1.png","banner_id":12},{"id":6,"img":"new_2.png","banner_id":12}]}]
```

Vue.js

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    banner:[],
    search:'',
},
methods: {
    getBannerData: function() {
        axios.get('/case/ajax/33').then(response => {
            this.banner = response.data.banner;
        });
    },
},
mounted: function() {
   this.getBannerData();
},
computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.banner(value => {
        return value.banner_img.filter(bannerImg => {
        return bannerImg.img.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        });
      })
    }
}
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="ImgFilter" v-model="search">
<div v-for="value in filteredList">
    <img v-for="imgs in value.banner_img" :src="imgs.img" height="100">
</div>
```

Then I try this filteredList

```
return value.banner_img.filter(bannerImg => {
       return bannerImg.img.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
});
```

but is not work..

Please give me some advices～！

Comment: `this.banner` is an array, you are using it like a function inside `filteredList`, shouldn't that be `this.banner.filter`?

Comment: return  this.banner.filter(function(item) {
    return item.banner_img && item.banner_img.some(function(img) {
         return img.img.toLowerCase() === this.search.toLowerCase();
    });    
});

Comment: @MatJ oh~! thank you,Can you tell me how I can solve this?

Comment: this is not really answering a question, but if I may suggest to you to use a wonderful library called lodash (https://lodash.com/). It is great for doing various operations with all sorts type of data and much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
filterList:function()(
    var that = this;
    return this.banner.filter(function(item) { 
             return item.banner_img && item.banner_img.some(function(img) {          
                 return img.img && img.img.toLowerCase() === that.search.toLowerCase();           
             }); 
         });
   )
```

Comment: thank your reply, but is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: I guess then there might be some null values for image.

Comment: oh thank you!  is work! Excuse me,If I want to multiple search ,ex: search "img":"air_1.png” and "id":3,"img":"hot_1.png",

Comment: return img.img &&  that.search.indexOf(img.img.toLowerCase())>=0;

Comment: But in this case you will have to create another loop to make lowercase the search array values.